# C#: Round decimals for var made of Random

Tags: c#, rounding

I got this (C#) :

```
Random RNG = new Random();
decimal divab50 = RNG.Next(50,100);
decimal divbl50 = RNG.Next(6,50);
decimal decreturn = divab50 / divbl50;
Console.WriteLine(decreturn);
```

How can I round the decreturn var to two decimals? I've tried Math.Round and String.Format they don't seem to work for vars generated in RNG. I think. I'm new at c# just started

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't know or care that `decreturn` happened to come from a `Random`; all it sees is the value passed to it. Also, for future reference it'd be helpful to include what you already tried in the question because `Math.Round()` and `String.Format()` (which uses the same formatting as `Console.WriteLine()`) are the two common ways to do this (`decimal.ToString()` being a third).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your variable `decreturn` and do `Math.Round(decreturn, 2)` or `String.Format("{0:F2}", decreturn)`, it works as expected.

The following example is working:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random RNG = new Random();
        decimal divab50 = RNG.Next(50,100);
        decimal divbl50 = RNG.Next(6,50);
        decimal decreturn = divab50 / divbl50;
        decimal rounded = Math.Round(decreturn, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(rounded);
    }
}
```

Fiddle to test with `Math.Round`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/70LTrm

You could also apply `String.Format` for this purpose like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random RNG = new Random();
        decimal divab50 = RNG.Next(50,100);
        decimal divbl50 = RNG.Next(6,50);
        decimal decreturn = divab50 / divbl50;
        var rounded = String.Format("{0:F2}", decreturn);
        Console.WriteLine(rounded);
    }
}
```

Fiddle to test with `String.Format`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Yy8uU

Take a look to the documentation of [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1) and [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use either [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_) or an appropriate [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier) depending on your needs

- [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_)

> Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to a specified number
>   of fractional digits, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even
>   number.

- [The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier)

> The fixed-point (`"F"`) format specifier converts a number to a string
>   of the form `"-ddd.ddd…"` where each `"d"` indicates a digit (0-9). The
>   string starts with a minus sign if the number is negative.
>
> The precision specifier indicates the desired number of decimal
>   places. If the precision specifier is omitted, the current
>   `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits` property supplies the numeric
>   precision.

```
// this should be a static or an instance field
Random RNG = new Random();

// inside a method
decimal divab50 = RNG.Next(50,100);
decimal divbl50 = RNG.Next(6,50);
decimal decreturn = divab50 / divbl50;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(decreturn,2));
Console.WriteLine($"{decreturn:F2}");
```

**Example Output**

```
3.42
3.42
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SaQOA)

<sub>***Note*** : Creating a new instance of `Random` every time you need a random number will cause you issues. It will be best to use this as a `static` field or an instance member</sub>

Comment: I just instanced Random once, and use it every time I need a number generated, is this not recommended? I'm learning on a 6 year-old course on YT. Thank you for the answer and the note

Comment: @AndreiIon for further information and clarification on Random see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer everyone.

What worked for me was adding  "{0:F2}", to the WriteLine Method like this :

```
Random RNG = new Random();
decimal divab50 = RNG.Next(50,100);
decimal divbl50 = RNG.Next(6,50);
decimal decreturn = divab50 / divbl50;
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}",decreturn);
```

This also worked. I wasn't doing it right the first time.

```
decimal rounded = Math.Round(decreturn, 2);
Console.WriteLine(rounded);
```

Thank you everyone